# NullPointerException when returning to onActivityResult on some device

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
Intent pictureActionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
                pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, GALLERY_PICTURE);
```

And:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {            
            if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE)
            {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri); And......
```

For most of the device, it is fine, the `data.getData()` will return something..
But in Motorola, one device will have NullPointerException, and I checked that the `data.getData()` is null.
Is there any solution to solve this problem??
P.S. some other default application in this device can choose picture from gallery, so I assume there is some way to solve.  Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying the wrong `Intent`. Try this one instead:

`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);`